# Using PHP to access MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server

Having previously developed applications in Silverlight we are now moving to HTML5.  As part of this move towards a more open source approach I am considering using PHP to link to our MSSQL database instead of .NET.  Is there any good reason not to take this approach? (We have to keep MSSQL and Windows)

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for StackOverflow's Q&A format. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 1):

Accordingo to [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) There're a lot of functions to handle a MSSQL Database.

Anyway you should first loading the Driver as **MICROSOFT** says [Official SQL Server Site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx)

You can download the SQL Server 2005 Driver for PHP at the Microsoft Download Center. Included in the download are two .dll files: php_sqlsrv.dll and php_sqlsrv_ts.dll.
Loading the SQL Server 2005 Driver for PHP is similar to loading any PHP extension!

1. Put the extension file (php_sqlsrv.dll or php_sqlsrv_ts.dll) in the
   PHP extension directory.
2. Modify the php.ini file to include the extension.
   Depending on which version of the driver you want to load
   (non-thread-safe or thread-safe), you will need to add one of the
   following lines to the Dynamic Extensions section of your php.ini
   file:

   extension=php_sqlsrv.dll

   extension=php_sqlsrv_ts.dll
3. Restart the Web server.
4. Enjoy the API

After everythings you have to **configure** the SQL Server 2005+ Driver for PHP has three configuration options:

- **LogSubsystems**
  Use this option to turn the logging of subsystems on or off. The
  default setting is SQLSRV_LOG_SYSTEM_OFF (logging is turned off by
  default).
- **LogSeverity**
  Use this option to specify what to log after logging has been turned
  on. The default setting is SQLSRV_LOG_SEVERITY_ERROR (only errors are
  logged by default after logging has been turned on).
- **WarningsReturnAsErrors** By default, Driver for PHP
  treats warnings generated by sqlsrv functions as errors. Use the
  WarningsReturnAsErrors option to change this behavior. The default
  setting for this option is true.

Note   There are exceptions to this rule. For example, the warning generated by changing the database context is never treated as an error.

At the and there's only a few last things that you have to keep in mind
the *sqlsrv_connect* function is used to establish a connection to the server.

```
$serverName = "(local)";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"myDatabase");
/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);
if( $conn === false )
      { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }
```

By default, the sqlsrv_connect function uses **Windows Authentication** to establish a connection. In most scenarios, this means that the Web server's process identity or thread identity (if the Web server is using impersonation) is used to connect to the server, not an end-user's identity.

The sqlsrv_connect function accepts two parameters: $serverName and $connectionOptions (optional).

- **$serverName** This required parameter is used to specify the name of
  the server to which you want to connect. In the code above, a
  connection is established to the local server. This parameter can
  also be use to specify a SQL Server instance or a port number. For
  example:

  $serverName = "myServer\instanceName";

-or-

```
$serverName = "myServer, 1521";
```

- **$connectionOptions** This optional parameter is an array of key-value pairs that set options on the connection. For
  more information, see sqlsrv_connect in the product documentation.

*Note*   The UID and PWD options must be set in the $connectionOptions parameter to log into the server with SQL Server Authentication.

*Note*    The FormatErrors function that is shown in the example is a custom function for formatting error output.

Comment: If you're going to copy paste content from a website, you should at least include a link to the source http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1258.accessing-sql-server-databases-from-php.aspx

Comment: Sorry the question was seen as inappropriate but the answer was really helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: @DavidCarver mask as answer if it really helpful please :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using php (running on IIS on Windows Server 2003 and 2008) and Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008R2) in a high availability production environment for almost 2 years now.

The drivers from php to SQL server were a bit unstable in the beginning, but as long as you get the latest drivers it is very robust.

The PHP and SQL Server combination performs better than the .net implementation in my environment.